# count blog post likes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, blog, like

I want to display number of "likes" each blog post has earned.

I want to show that count against respective post in different column lets say "Like Count".
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this out of box but you can get this if wrote some code. Check the below answer from MSFT social forum, he had also code and some tuning in it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/709cb31d-6a1b-4903-a703-f6b2d7bf3738/count-number-of-likes-on-blog-posts-on-sharepoint-2010

here is very good blog post series to get I like it counters.

[Part 1](http://www.eliostruyf.com/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-1/), [Part2](http://www.eliostruyf.com/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-2/), [Part 3](http://www.eliostruyf.com/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-3/), [Part4](http://www.eliostruyf.com/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-4-2/)