# Is there a way to query for items a user has "liked"?

Tags: social, content-search-web-part

I am trying to pull together a list of items / documents a user has "liked."  I saw that there's a crawled property `ows_LikedBy`, but no managed property, so I created a managed property `LikedBy` and mapped it to the crawled property.

I tried to set up a Content Search web part with a simple query of `LikedBy:{User.Name}`, but that is not giving any results.  I then noticed that the `LikedBy` field is hidden, which means it's not getting indexed.

So is there a way to query for items a user has liked?  Either through a Content Search web part / keyword query, or through some other means?

I considered un-hiding the field so it will get crawled, but I don't like the idea of changing the settings on a base SP field.

Also, I saw [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/117572/8992) about using SPServices to get the items a user has liked, but `GetListItems` will only return items from a particular list, and I need results from across the entire web app.

Comment: In SP2010 "I like it" was a social tag applied to a content, and data for 'liked' content were retrieved through Social Data web service, but this is probably not your case.

Comment: Actually I started looking into the Social Data services, but I am having some trouble getting results, and I'm not sure if it is because of something wrong with my dev environment, or if "I like it" is no longer a social tag in SP2013.  Can anyone confirm is "I like it" is still a social tag in SP2013, and that it is the default tag that gets applied when a user clicks the "Like" button?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the SocialTagManager class...there is no call to get a count for a whole site...apparently you must do a crawl

Here are some references...

[count blog post likes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105351/count-blog-post-likes)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/get-all-the-social-tags-for-the-specified-url-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialtagmanager(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.eliostruyf.com/take-your-sharepoint-social-features-to-the-next-level-with-i-like-it-and-tags-counters-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I found the a workaround if someone is stuck on the same issue like me.

1. Create your own "`LikedBy`" column
2. Create an `ItemUpdated` event receiver on the list where you copy the out of the box `LikedBy` column to your custom liked by column.
3. Do a `systemUpdate()` in the event receiver to not change the modified date.

`properties.ListItem["My_x0020_Liked_x0020_By"] = properties.ListItem["LikedBy"];
properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();`

4. Get this custom field in your crawled properies and make sure it is mapped to be able to use it in your content search webpart.